# Company year end party - taking along my personal laptop to do some personal work

Tags: company-culture, company-policy

If I bring my personal laptop to my company's year end party, will it make me an outsider? Also, I will need to ask the hotel staff for WiFi.
I'm not seeking attention, I have some personal documents to prepare and I'm seriously busy.

I'm sure that nobody else will bring laptops there but seriously I need to.
It's not against the company policy.

Any idea on this one, will that hit the threshold of being an outsider?  This is clearly something which is not against company policy but company-culture (non officially defined) will may overlap this.

Comment: Just to clarify... you are asking whether it is ok to do personal work at the company party. Are you not planning on socializing? Are you expected to be there? Are you unable to be excused from attending the party?

Comment: Don't go to the party if you have other stuff to do.

Comment: @Maarten Need to go to the party as well. Because there are few parties for a year. Good food, etc etc. So need to have that, as well as I need to have my personal things as well.

Comment: This is really just opinion based.  There's nothing to stop you from using a laptop at a company event.  You may well get distracted by other attendees or you could spend your time in the hotel foyer away from the event itself.  It's your choice.

Comment: @Pᴇᴛᴇ Yes that would be an option. But have you done that? and have you seen people done that? Have they done that without getting outlined? Hotel foyer right ? So nobody will notice that I would bring the laptop either.

Comment: Just do one things at a time - either go to the party or stay at home and do work. Your choice. Besides taking a laptop to a party there is danger of it getting lost or broken.

Comment: Hi, I took the liberty of editing your question to fix some typos. Also, the words "outline" / "outlinear" you use do not make sense. I corrected this to "outsider". Is that what you meant?

Comment: @sandundhammika - It's your choice.  There's no do this/do that answer.

Comment: So if I get this right, you are asking, "I want to do A and B, but I can only do one thing at a time. How can I do both?"

Comment: @MaskedMan , what I asked is how to do both A and B without getting infractions due to local office culture at the same time. Without giving the impression that "attraction seeking". 
There is a option as Pete told. WIthout getting noticed.

Comment: In any part there are some non interesting time wasting slots and even not interested to hear. So I can safely cut those time to do my personal document, But need to be smart enough not to get noticed.

Comment: Re close votes: Voted as _primarily opinion based_ where all the answers basically say _don't do it_

Comment: "*So need to have that*". No. No you don't. You *want* to have that. I suppose the proverb "you can't have your cake and eat it too" is new to you? If you're so utterly busy then you're booking yourself too tight and you need to make sacrifices, not going to this party being one of them. Physically being in the room and taking advantage of the free food is not attending a party. It's disrespectful and that goes for every type of party, which means this also isn't really workplace-specific.

Comment: @Lilienthal , I can see your personal infraction about that. Taking advantage of free food. But however it's your personal infraction right. Don't take professional things into personal. If that downvote is all about that personal infraction, then seriously this question does not deserve that downvote.

Comment: @Lilienthal I however found my answer, but somebody else will find this thread useful in future.

Comment: If you need a polite solution, either tell the people beforehand that you might be late and finish your personal work before going to the party or excuse yourself early and finish it afterwards. I go to the most laptop-prone office parties (computer science university department) and even here it would be seen as incredibly rude to sit in a corner staring at the laptop just taking breaks to get more food. It is less rude to not attend than to ruin the mood for everyone else and create awkward situations for others trying to socialise with you.

Comment: Got it what you mean. Many people don't likeythat one bring a laptop to a party. Many thinks it's not fair. However it's an information, yes it also could be posted/edit as an answer. It's good information. But not a reason to downvote this question , cos that info may be useful to somebody who dig this question later.

Comment: Please let me know if the question is not polite , so I can edit it to polite.

Comment: Finish whatever you need to do, then show up later?

Comment: The only way bringing a laptop to a party is acceptable is if it stays in the bag the entire time. In other words, only bring it if you were working somewhere else and didn't have time to drop it off at home before the party, and even then I would try to stick it in a corner or coat check so you don't have to carry it around all night.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Obviously, I don't know your company, but I can't imagine a scenario where sitting at a company party working on your laptop would be better than excusing yourself. People *might* notice if you don't attend and wonder why, but you working at the party *will* be noticed and could really distract your colleagues or superiors from enjoying the party. Find out if you can gracefully opt out of the party. If participation is mandatory, actually participate (you don't need to drink, in fact, you shouldn't anyway) and leave as early as acceptable to conduct the urgent business.

**Edit:**

*OP has indicated that the party is optional, but he wants to attend.*

You need to sort out your priorities. You can't have both the party and working on something. Decide what is more important to you and do that. Don't work at a company party. You wouldn't get done much of the work anyway.

Comment: Sri Lanka, very same as Indian culture. However, is that bringing a laptop is normal in USA? But bring the phone is oky right ? Since I don't own an expensive mobile device to have all the applications and functions that laptop provides. And the party is not mandatory. It's optional, however the fact is need to enjoy the party too, because good food, good music etc. Since there are few parties for a one year.

Comment: You need to sort out your priorities. Apparently, you have something urgent to do but *want* to go to the party. You can only do one of those, not both.

Comment: Hi, and what about the US work culture ? is that also same ? Nobody bring laptops to the party? Just curious, I think I got the answer, I can mark it 'accepted' however keeping few hours.

Comment: I have never worked in the US. I wouldn't want to work for a company where people work at parties. I would consider having no parties at all preferable to that.

Answer (score 13):

No, don't work at company parties, it is strange and it will draw attention.

- Go enjoy the party and postpone your personal tasks, if you really want to go. Try to do your other tasks another time.
- Stay home because you are too busy, and ask your colleagues later on how the party was.
- **Work for a few hours and join the party later.**

I'd go for the latter, if I really wanted to go to the party.

Comment: Strange in USA too? Just curious, not a part of the question.

Comment: @sandundhammika: I think it would be strange in most cultures - the point of a party is to socialize with others, and being there, but being unapprochable is at odds with this.

Comment: @sleske , for me it's different. Being social does not get me any new technical opportunities, in here, may true in US or something like that. I know clearly they don't have much to offer. So pointless to get socialized there, but only for getting NOT noticed. However food is great, the reason why I'm going.

Comment: @sandundhammika: Hm, in my experience new contacts are always a benefit, but that's your call to make. If you are just going for the food, excusing yourself for the work is probably the best option.

Comment: I agree about new contracts, but same people we are work with. Same families of them. No opportunities on it, that's what I know certain. So that value is depend of audience right? If the audience is higher , then it's higher seeking opportunities so that would be useful.

Comment: @sandundhammika: In my experience, even if you meet people you know, there is opportunity for networking. But this is getting off-topic. Consider asking a separate question about networking opportunities at company parties if you want to pursue this further.

Comment: +1 for the part in bold.  There's no reason you have to be at the party from the moment it starts until the moment it ends.  Show up a little late, enjoy it for an hour or two, leave early.

Answer (score 5):

Bringing a personal laptop is no problem at all - I do it all the time. However, actually using that laptop is more tricky.

As already indicated in the other answers, working at the party where others can see you will come over as strange - it's a party, you are supposed to socialize, eat good food and have fun. Sitting in front of your laptop and working will at least make you look strange.

My personal advice would be:

- If you only need to work for a short time (15-30 minutes), and cannot do the work at another time, then briefly leave the party, try to find a quiet spot, do the work and come back. If it is a hotel, maybe you can sit in the lobby, or nicely ask staff if you can use an empty meeting room. That way you do your work without annoying others. Leaving the party and coming back may look strange, too, but less strange than working in front of others - plus if the party is of the standup type, others may not even notice you were gone for a while.
- If you need to work for hours, then there is no point in going to the party. Sitting there working while others celebrate will not only look strange, it will not be any fun for you either. So just skip the party.